# how to reset password and username on cisco IR829GW by PUTTY?

Tags: putty, cisco-anyconnect, cisco-router, cisco-jabber

I have bought an used  IOT operational dashboard router and as i expected it is asking me for access verification from the old owner , how can i do a reset factory to enable a new username and password? i have tested with `username: cisco` `password:cisco`and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the Cisco Router documentation, and do a full hardware reset.

This will give you a chance to enter a new user name and password. This will work when you otherwise cannot log in.

This is a universal way to fix this issue.

Here is the reset documentation.

[How to reset the IR829 to factory settings](https://community.cisco.com/t5/edge-computing-infrastructure/how-to-reset-the-ir829-to-factory-settings/td-p/3502744)